# Kafka Producer message not available in Topic in EC2 linux

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-ec2

I have written the kafka producer and partitioned in Eclipse in windows machine. My Kafka cluster is running in ec2 linux. I am able to execute the kafaka producer code from eclipse but I don't see the topics in ec2 box.

```
Produce code :
package com.panda.kafka.training;
import java.util.*;   
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer; 
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

public class PandaKafkaProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long events = Long.parseLong(args[0]); 
        Random rnd = new Random(); 
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "ec2-xx-yy-zzz-212.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9092"); 
        //props.put("producer.type", "sync"); 
        props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder"); 
        props.put("partitioner.class", "com.panda.kafka.training.PandaKafkaPartitioner");
        props.put("request.required.acks", "1"); 
        props.put("producer.type","async");

        ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
        Producer<String, String> producer = new Producer<String,
                String>(config); 
        for (long nEvents = 0; nEvents < events; nEvents++) 
        { System.out.println("creating event "+nEvents); 
        long runtime = new Date().getTime(); 
        String ip = "192.168.2."+ rnd.nextInt(255); 
        String msg = runtime + ",www.vulab.com," + ip; KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>("vulab123", ip, msg);
        producer.send(data); 
        } 
        producer.close(); 
    }

}


Server Properties file:
# The port the socket server listens on
port=9092

# Hostname the broker will bind to. If not set, the server will bind to all interfaces
host.name=localhost

# Hostname the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, it uses the
# value for "host.name" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
advertised.host.name=ec2-xx-yy-zzz-212.compute-1.amazonaws.com

# The port to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use. If this is not set,
# it will publish the same port that the broker binds to.
advertised.port=0000


Producer properties file:
# list of brokers used for bootstrapping knowledge about the rest of the cluster
# format: host1:port1,host2:port2 ...
metadata.broker.list=52.2.202.212:0000

# name of the partitioner class for partitioning events; default partition spreads data randomly
#partitioner.class=

# specifies whether the messages are sent asynchronously (async) or synchronously (sync)
producer.type=sync

Output from Producer in ec2:
[ec2-user@ip-xxxx bin]$ sh kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list xxxx:yyy.zzzz:9092 --topic vulab123
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Any detailed explanation will help a lot.

Comment: Is 9092 port open on EC2 node ?

Answer (score 3):

Please find the details answer. I have a windows machine where eclipse is installed and I have created Maven project for Kafka. I wanted to send some message to kafaka cluster (EC2) from windows eclipse. I have one machine doing all the kafka stuff.

Note: 
Java Producer Code. You have to make sure that the complete DNS name is mentioned here.

```
props.put("metadata.broker.list", "ec2-52-xx-yyy-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9092"); 

props.put("advertised.host.name", "ec2-52-xx-yyy-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9092");
```

Step1:

```
I started a new EC2 Linux machine and installed Kafka.
wget http://mirror.sdunix.com/apache/kafka/0.8.1.1/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.tgz - See more at: http://vulab.com/blog/?p=576#sthash.GiMHbvXm.dpuf

tar -xzf kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.tgz
```

Step2:

1. Allowed ssh and all trafic in inbound rules in EC2 Security group.
2. Add the public ip (EC2) in /etc/hosts/ file in windows machine where 
       eclipse is installed.

Step3:

```
Modified the kafka server properties files. I put the exact DNS name.
    # The port the socket server listens on
    port=9092

# Hostname the broker will bind to. If not set, the server will bind to all interfaces
host.name=ec2-52-xx-yyy-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com

# Hostname the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, it uses the
# value for "host.name" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
advertised.host.name=ec2-52-xx-yyy-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com
zookeeper.connect=ec2-52-xx-yyy-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2181
```

Step4:

Commands Executed

```
    1. sh zookeeper-server-start.sh /home/ec2/user/kafka/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties

    2. sh kafka-server-start.sh /home/ec2-user/kafka/kafka/config/server.properties

    3 .sh kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper ec2-52-xx-yyy-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic spanda20

    4. sh kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list ec2-52-xx-yyy-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9092 --topic spanda20--sync 

    5.sh kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper ec2-52-xx-yyy-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2181 --topic spanda20 --from-beginning
```

I could see all the messages in consumer.